# Exception when trying to use navigator

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am getting an exception: FlutterError (Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator. The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.)

This is the important code of the first page (Skipped some code with ... that wasn't relevant):

```
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'register.dart';

void main() async {
...
runApp(const MyApp());

}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
            textTheme: GoogleFonts.interTextTheme(
          Theme.of(context).textTheme,
        )),
home: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            ...

                Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => SecondRoute()));
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "Forgot Password?",
                        style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
             ...

        ),
    ));
```

}
}

This is the second page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SecondRoute extends Navigator {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

There are no syntax errors only exceptions thrown when the code is run. I have tried already looking for the solution but the other way of putting the material app in the runApp() method, to my understanding doesn't work for the way I use the Text Theme and use context.

Let me know if I need to give more code or context.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```dart
class SecondRoute extends Navigator {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

to:

```dart
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Edit, also move the scaffold from `_MyAppState` into it's own widget.

```dart
class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print('hello');
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
              );
            },
            child: Text(
              "Forgot Password?",
              style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And then use in `_MyAppState` like so:

```dart
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          textTheme: GoogleFonts.interTextTheme(
        Theme.of(context).textTheme,
      )),
      home: FirstRoute(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this should work

Comment: I had it like this originally and changed it to navigator to fix the problem, but it still doesn't work either way. Still giving me the same exception.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Is there anyway I can keep it with a stateful widget because the rest of my code is dependent on it being a stateful widget.

Comment: `FirstRoute` can be a stateful widget instead if you want. The issue was caused by the `BuildContext` object. In your original code, the `BuildContext` was defined outside of the `MaterialApp`, but separating the route into it's own widget solves this problem. An alternative approach would be to use a `Builder` widget and use the `BuildContext` from the `Builder` widget.